# Certificate subjectAlternativeName with wildcard IP

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard

i need create a certificate, which will be used as TLS server authority on any random host in the isolated LAN. Can i use in the subjectAlternativeName field some wildcard for IP instead domains like 10.0.0.255 or 10.0.0.0/24 for that purpose?

P.S. any host in the LAN can be client for distributed net of servers, which are can be started on any host and connected to fluid dynamic greed behind load balanser, which manage connections in this crease network )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) (assuming you're talking about HTTPS) has to say on this:

> ```
> In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a 
> hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present  
> in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI.
> ```

This would exclude usage of wildcard or subnet notations.

The more recent [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-1.7.2), which aims to harmonise identification across other protocols, explicitly excludes IP addresses from its scope.

This being said, you may find that there are some non-compliant clients out there with their own interpretation (there are some that allow usage of an IP address in the CN of the Subject DN, for example). I wouldn't recommend counting on it generally.

It seems a bit surprising that you'd want to use TLS at all on what you call an "isolated LAN". In addition, if you're in control of that LAN, you could assign names to your machines and use hostname matchine.

Comment: this is scientific tasks solving greed, which was designed 8 years ago as university /16 LAN without DHCP server. I am setup dhcp3 in this network, but many hosts present, which configured as static IP and without proper domain or hostname settings, so i can`t imagine wildcard domain for create universal certificate. 

Used software allow establish security connections by own protocol using SSL, and i need to implement encryption in that greed. But I can use only IP wildcards, so i don`t mater how create this certificate, or as alternative create 65536 server certificates

Comment: Presumably, you mean "grid", not "greed"?

Comment: yes. and i found decision for my problem - i am create script, which generate certificates according on information from form on inner site, where host domain field is required and setup core for reject open connections with notify about requirements and link to the registration page of certificates issue. Your right - it is no ways for add wildcard IP in the certificates - only domains wildcards can be specified.